# Python threading: how to limit active threads number?

Tags: python, multithreading

What I need - to have 20 active threads. No more. I need the way to control that the number is no more than 20. And in the end of python script, i need to make sure if all this threads are closed. How to do so?

First try - to sleep 0.1 second. But it is pretty random decision and I have error from time to time: `Connection pool is full, discarding connection`

```
list_with_file_paths = [...]
slice_20 = list_with_file_paths[:20]
threads = []
for i in slice_20:
    th = threading.Thread(target=process_data, args=(i,))
    print('active count:', threading.active_count())
    if threading.active_count() < 20:
        th.start()
    else:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        th.start()
    threads.append(th)
```

Second try - to append all threads in one list and .join() them. But it is not connected with number of 20 threads.

```
list_with_file_paths = [...]
slice_20 = list_with_file_paths[:20]
threads = []
for j in range(10): # I take every 20 items from list_with_file_paths but I have shortened for this example 
    for i in slice_20:
        th = threading.Thread(target=process_data, args=(i,))
        print('active count:', threading.active_count())
        if threading.active_count() < 20:
            th.start()
        else:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            th.start()
        threads.append(th)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

Is [Limit number of active threads Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61187321/limit-number-of-active-threads-python) only chance to  limit active threads number?

Comment: You can use a [`ThreadPool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool)

Comment: Classic solution would be a semaphore initialized with 20 units.